# Как реализовать формулу с вводом множества данных не дублируя переменные?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

столкнулся с проблемой, написал формулу (простую): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать на JS такую формулу (допустим на 3-4 J):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

J (если что в файле-техничке в глобал вынесены у меня, тут записал как 6.9 и t3 - то же самое), добавляю их в формулу просто такими же значениями (предварительно подключив, понятно).

```js
let resultVmin;
function breakWayMin() {
    const form = document.querySelector('#formInputMin');
    const Sj = +form[0].value;
    const L = +form[1].value;
    resultVmin = 1.8 * 0.25 * 6.9 + (Math.sqrt(25.92 * ((Sj - L)) * 6.9));
    console.log(+resultVmin.toFixed(2));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultVmin');
    result.innerText = `Результат: ${Number(resultVmin.toFixed(2))}`;
    return +resultVmin.toFixed(2);

}
```

```html
<h1>Мин скорость</h1>

<form id="formInputMin">
    <div>
        <label>Sюз</label>
        <input type="number">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>L</label>
        <input type="number">
    </div>

</form>

<button onclick="breakWayMin()">Результат Vmin</button>
<h2 id="resultVmin"></h2>
```

и ещё вопрос - если у меня куча J - как их продублировать что-ли, чтобы не копировать в техническом JS файле, ибо их там очень много( Чтобы (может) создать J2 а значения оно подтягивало из J (ну это второстепенный вопрос). Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Сумбур какой-то в вопросе. Похоже, что вам нужно в цикле вычислить значение под корнем, используя J[i] из массива

Comment: @MBo, в первой формуле всё считает нормально, сюда чуть криво закинул(

Comment: Значения `S[i]` и `J[i]` передаете массивом. Первое действие - считаете результат из массива, потом передаете полученное значение в формулу. Вид массива 1) Двумерный вида `[ [s1, j1], [s2, j2] ]` 2) Массив объектов `[ {s: 1, j: 2}, {s:4, j:3} ]`

Comment: @SwaD, а J2, J3.. Значения, я так понял, надо заново задавать так же как и J (которое уже есть)?

Comment: Можете кодом показать, что у вас есть сейчас с этими переменными и как вы планируете их вводить?

Comment: @SwaD, я сейчас не за ноутом, пока могу сказать что J и t3 - берутся из common.js (технички, где все глобалки записаны), S я задаю сам через форму вписываю

Comment: @SwaD, function breakWay3() {
    const form = document.querySelector('#formInput3');
    const S = +form[0].value;
    const [ [S1, J], [S2, J2] ] = [ {S: 1, J: 2}, {S:4, J:3} ].map(a => +form[a].value);
    const result = 1.8 * t3 * J + (Math.sqrt(25.92 * (Sj * J)));
    return +result.toFixed(2)
}

function make3(){
    const result = breakWay3();
    const div = document.querySelector('#resultF4');
    div.innerText = `Результат: ${result}`;

}

Comment: @SwaD, я пока не совсем понимаю двухмерные массивы, если честно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример реализации множественного ввода значений без необходимости создания кучи переменных

```js
    const form = document.getElementById('formInputMin');
    const resField = document.querySelector('#resultVmin')
    const variables = [];
    const values = {
      s: 0,
      l: 0
    }

    function inputVariable(type, idx) {
      const inp = document.createElement('input');
      inp.type = 'number';
      inp.value = values[type];
      inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
        variables[idx][type] = this.value
      })
      return inp;
    }

    function craeteDiv(label, len) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = `<label>${label}(${len+1})</label>`
      div.append(inputVariable(label, len))
      return div;
    }

    function addInput() {
      form.append(craeteDiv('s', variables.length));
      form.append(craeteDiv('l', variables.length));
      variables.push({ ...values });
    }
    addInput();

    function breakWayMin() {
      const sjL = variables.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.s * item.l, 0);
      const result = 1.8 * 0.25 * 6.9 + (Math.sqrt(25.92 * (sjL) * 6.9));
      resField.innerHTML = `Результат: ${result.toFixed(2)}`;      
    }
```

```html
<h1>Мин скорость</h1>

<form id="formInputMin">

</form>
<br />
<button onclick="addInput()">Еще переменная</button>
<br />
<button onclick="breakWayMin()">Результат Vmin</button>
<hr />
<h2 id="resultVmin"></h2>
```

Comment: я утром закину в Вебшторм, там вместо 6.9 (из формулы) и 0.25 подкину J и t3 (глобалки),добавится ещё 2 поля, по идее должно же будет работать? Если будет то будет пушка вообще) (но я уже сейчас уже отмечу как решение, спасибо Вам ОГРОМНОЕ)

Comment: @Maks Если вместо ваших констрант передать переменные из справочника, так же будет работать, но, что называется, без костылей и хард кода

Comment: та я просто уже с пятницы голову ломал как это реализовать (с минимум затрат), готов был уже кучу раз формулу переписать.. а толку - нагромождение кода только будет( У меня сама база J больше 2к строк выходит( Я боюсь что завтра не прокатит у меня закинуть addJGlobal сюда а оно покажет что не будет дублировать его значения на J2 и тд.. Потому что S2, S3 и тд там нажал кнопку и погнали и J привязан к данным в common.js и выбирается из селектора( И как-то стрёмно мне ради J2, J3 и тд 2к строк копировать несколько раз.. Тогда common.js будет сильно большой по размеру

Comment: @Maks Пробуйте, не получится, приходите, поможем, чем сможем

Comment: спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ за помощь) Я думаю, насчёт дублирования J вопрос будет у меня (прям чую)) Но это будет уже не сегодня)

Comment: добрый день, попробовал сегодня внедрить туда глобалки мои - не вышло( Я такое раньше не делал просто, труднее понять что к чему, ниже скину код

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Behemoth0/w9yndgxs/65/

Comment: Получается что у меня J и t3 заданы через селектор, а сам ввожу я значение S в форме

Comment: @Maks У меня нет доступа к этому ресурсу(видимо закрыт глобально, ВПН не использую).

Comment: я уже с горем-пополам решил) J и t3 подставил глобально, чуть переписал константы, проверил и работает) Но такая задумка (как Ваша идея, очень классная, особенно для такого типа формул)