# Как сделать добавление форм кнопкой и чтобы последующие формы учитывали добавление новых (добавленных) значений

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Подскажите как сделать кнопкой добавление новых значений Va, например: нажал кнопку ("+" под первым Va ,например) - появилось Va2, нажал еще раз кнопку "+" (под  - добавилось Va3. И чтобы последующие формулы выводили результат для нужного количества Va (сколько добавил Va) столько и результатов.

```js
let resultTt;
let resultStd;
let resultTt1;
let resultSa;
let resultSo;

function getGlobal() {
  return Number(document.querySelector('#JGlobal').value)
}
let J = getGlobal();
document.querySelector('#JGlobal').addEventListener('change', function() {
  J = getGlobal();

})

function getT1Global() {
  return Number(document.querySelector('#T1Global').value)
}
let t1 = getT1Global();
document.querySelector('#T1Global').addEventListener('change', function() {
  t1 = getT1Global();

})

function getT2Global() {
  return Number(document.querySelector('#T2Global').value)
}
let t2 = getT2Global();
document.querySelector('#T2Global').addEventListener('change', function() {
  t2 = getT2Global();

})

function getT3Global() {
  return Number(document.querySelector('#T3Global').value)
}
let t3 = getT3Global();
document.querySelector('#T3Global').addEventListener('change', function() {
  t3 = getT3Global();

})

function getGlobalVa() {
  return Number(document.querySelector('#VaGlobal').querySelector('input').value)
}
let va = getGlobalVa();
document.querySelector('#VaGlobal').addEventListener('change', function() {
  va = getGlobalVa();

})

// 1 формула - значение Tt:
function breakWayTt() {
  const form = document.querySelector('#formInputTt');
  resultTt = va / (3.6 * J);
  console.log(+resultTt.toFixed(4));
  const result = document.querySelector('#resultTt');
  result.innerText = `Результат: ${Number(resultTt.toFixed(4))}`;
  return +resultTt.toFixed(4);

}

// 2 формула - значение Sтд:
function breakWayStd() {
  const form = document.querySelector('#formInputStd');
  const Sj = +form[0].value;
  const L = +form[1].value;
  const C = +form[2].value;
  resultStd = Sj + va * t3 / 7.2 - L - C;
  console.log(+resultStd.toFixed(2));
  const result = document.querySelector('#resultStd');
  result.innerText = `Результат: ${Number(resultStd.toFixed(2))}`;
  return +resultStd.toFixed(2);

}

// 3 формула - значение Tt1:
function breakWayTt1() {
  resultTt1 = resultTt - (Math.sqrt(resultTt ** 2 - (2 * resultStd) / J + (t3 ** 2) / 4));
  console.log(+resultTt1.toFixed(4));
  const result = document.querySelector('#resultTt1');
  result.innerText = `Результат: ${Number(resultTt1.toFixed(4))}`;
  return +resultTt1.toFixed(4);
}

// 4 формула - значение Sa:
function breakWaySa() {
  const form = document.querySelector('#formInputSa');
  const Tp = +form[0].value;
  resultSa = (Tp - resultTt1) * (va / 3.6) + resultStd;
  console.log(+resultSa.toFixed(2));
  const result = document.querySelector('#resultSa');
  result.innerText = `Результат: ${Number(resultSa.toFixed(2))}`;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formula 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>При торможении</h1>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label>J1:</label>
        <input type="text" name="team" id="JGlobal" list="team_list">
        <datalist id="team_list">
          <option value="6.9">6.9 м3 мокрый</option>
          <option value="7.5">7.5 м3 сухой</option>
        </datalist>
      </div>
      <form>
        <div>
          <label>t1:</label>
          <select id="T1Global">
            <option disabled>выберите значение (надо выбрать - не будет просто так работать)</option>
            <option>1.0</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
      <form>
        <div>
          <label>t2:</label>
          <select id="T2Global">
            <option disabled>выберите значение (надо выбрать - не будет просто так работать)</option>
            <option>0.2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
      <form>
        <div>
          <label>t3:</label>
          <select id="T3Global">
            <option disabled>выберите значение (надо выбрать - не будет просто так работать)</option>
            <option>0.25</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
      <form id="VaGlobal">
        <div>
          <label>Va</label>
          <input type="number">
        </div>
      </form>
      <h1>Значение Tt</h1>
      <form id="formInputTt"></form>
      <button onclick="breakWayTt()">Результат V</button>
      <h2 id="resultTt"></h2>
      <h1>Значение Sтд</h1>
      <form id="formInputStd">
        <div>
          <label>Sj</label>
          <input type="number" value="9.3">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>L</label>
          <input type="number" value="2.52">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>C</label>
          <input type="number" value="0.838">
        </div>
      </form>
      <button onclick="breakWayStd()">Результат Sтд</button>
      <h2 id="resultStd"></h2>
      <h1>Значение Tt1</h1>
      <form id="formInputTt1"></form>
      <button onclick="breakWayTt1()">Результат Tt1</button>
      <h2 id="resultTt1"></h2>
      <h1>Значение Sa</h1>
      <form id="formInputSa">
        <div>
          <label>Tп</label>
          <input type="number" value="1.91">
        </div>
      </form>
      <button onclick="breakWaySa()">Результат Sa</button>
      <h2 id="resultSa"></h2>
      <button onclick="breakWaySo()">Результат So</button>
      <h2 id="resultSo"></h2>
      <button onclick="startAll()">Результат Общий</button>
      <h2 id="startAll"></h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SwaD, Гуру, нужна Ваша помощь)

Comment: Я же вам показывал [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493663/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5) Как можно динамически создавать поля под данные и потом к ним обращаться

Comment: @SwaD, я вчера пытался (честное слово) переделать тот Ваш вариант, но у меня не вышло( (я сегодня только из-за глобалок чтобы вопрос задать час этот код вписывал без глобалок внешних) Я просто не понимаю как сделать чтобы следующие формулы брали потом уже новый созданный результат. А формулы там связаны последовательно, кроме последней, она автономно берёт Va просто. Поэтому и решил спросить знающих людей

Comment: @SwaD, и ещё там была ж 1 формула с 1 меняющимся результатом, а тут выходит добавление Va, но чтобы уже формула считала там 1,2,3..Va и следующие формулы видели сколько новых результатов выходит и учитывали это

Comment: @SwaD, из моих формул - это самая глобальная задача, которую мне надо как-то решить( Больше беспокоить не буду по таким глобальным мелочам, помогите последний раз тут пожалуйста

Comment: Вам бы по хорошему вообще все переписать ) Вот есть у вас 1 поле Va, значение которого просто считывается и сохраняется. Если появится 2е поле Va, то что должно происходить? сумма?

Comment: @SwaD, когда появляется второе поле Va2 (например) то формула Tt (первая) ну и последующие за ней должны пересчитать и вывести и Va и Va2..Vn(условно сколько бы их не было) результаты.. и так следующие формулы должны учитывать что этих результата уже 2,3...n а не один

Comment: Не понятно. Например `resultStd = Sj + va * t3 / 7.2 - L - C;` Вот тут понятно, есть va и как бы ОК. Как вы измените эту строку, если у вас будет 2 va?

Comment: @SwaD, я в итоге тоже  к этому пришёл.. И решил спросить как корректно это сделать в JS. Обозначить как-то не Va а "значением", которое будет пересчитывать каждый раз новое Va и сохранять результат (ну в теории)

Comment: Это вопрос не про JS, а про математику. Выше формула текущая. И вот у нас появилось va1 и va2. Как эта формула должна измениться? Какой вид у нее будет?

Comment: @SwaD, а, не так понял.. извините) второй раз с новым Va2 и тд.. формула будет: resultStd = Sj + va2 * t3 / 7.2 - L - C;.. будет меняться индекс Va только

Comment: А результат первого куда тогда пихать, если каждый раз персчитывается? Вот посмотрите фукнцию `breakWayStd` и скажите, при 2-х va какой результат и куда должен вернуться? Сейчас в одно поле записывается один результат. А если 2 раза считаем, то что будет являться результатом?

Comment: @SwaD, результата должно быть оба, один под другим. Может как-то оно будет прописывать const result = document.querySelector('#resultStd2'); (при добавленном Va2) при Va3 const result = document.querySelector('#resultStd3'); rкак-нибудь так.. Или чтобы оно запоминало результат и оставляло при Va (первом) и ниже под этим же результатом когда пересчитало выводило результат при Va2, Va3.. Va n

Comment: У вас добрую половину кода придется переписать. Что бы динамически это все считалось, va надо превратить в массив значений, а все остальные фукнции должны бегать по массиву и забирать оттуда данные, как следствие, каждая фукнция должна еще под новый расчет новые поля под себя создавать...

Comment: @SwaD, я своими скромными знаниями точно не смогу( Я когда создавал этот вопрос понимал это(

Comment: @Swad, буду ОЧЕНЬ признателен за помощь.. Прям ОООЧЕНЬ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не все, но как концепт под развитие...

```js
  let resultTt;
  let resultStd;

  function getGlobal() {
    return Number(document.querySelector('#JGlobal').value)
  }
  let J = getGlobal();
  document.querySelector('#JGlobal').addEventListener('change', function() {
    J = getGlobal();
    breakWayTtPaint()

  })

  function getT1Global() {
    return Number(document.querySelector('#T1Global').value)
  }
  let t1 = getT1Global();
  document.querySelector('#T1Global').addEventListener('change', function() {
    t1 = getT1Global();

  })

  function getT2Global() {
    return Number(document.querySelector('#T2Global').value)
  }
  let t2 = getT2Global();
  document.querySelector('#T2Global').addEventListener('change', function() {
    t2 = getT2Global();

  })

  function getT3Global() {
    return Number(document.querySelector('#T3Global').value)
  }
  let t3 = getT3Global();
  document.querySelector('#T3Global').addEventListener('change', function() {
    t3 = getT3Global();

  })

  const VA = {}
  const STD = {
    Sj: 9.3,
    L: 2.52,
    C: 0.838
  }
  const TT = {}
  const STDRES = {}

  let count = 0;

  const formVA = document.getElementById('VaGlobal');
  const resultTtTable = document.getElementById('resultTt');
  const formSTD = document.querySelector('#formInputStd');
  const resultSTD = document.querySelector('#resultStd');
  const resultTT1 = document.querySelector('#resultTt1');

  function inputVariable(id, TARGET, RELOAD) {
    const inp = document.createElement('input');
    inp.type = 'number';
    inp.value = TARGET[id];
    inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
      TARGET[id] = this.value
      RELOAD()
    })
    return inp;
  }

  function createDiv(label, TARGET, RELOAD, del) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `<label for="${label}">${label}</label>`
    div.append(inputVariable(label, TARGET, RELOAD))
    if (del) div.append(createDelBtn(label, TARGET));
    return div;
  }

  function createDelBtn(id, TARGET) {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerHTML = '-';
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      delete TARGET[id];
      formVA.innerHTML = '';
      createVA(true)
    })
    return btn;
  }

  function createVA(add) {
    if (!add) {
      const id = 'va' + ++count;
      VA[id] = 0;
      formVA.append(createDiv(id, VA, breakWayTtPaint, true));
    } else {
      for (let x in VA) {
        formVA.append(createDiv(x, VA, breakWayTtPaint, true))
      }
    }
    breakWayTtPaint()

  }
  createVA();

  function breakWayTtPaint() {
    let line = ''
    for (let x in VA) {
      line += `<div><span>При ${x} равной ${VA[x]}: </span><span>${breakWayTt(VA[x], x)}</span></div>`;
    }
    resultTtTable.innerHTML = line;
    breakWayStdPrint()
  }

  // 1 формула - значение Tt:
  function breakWayTt(va, x) {
    console.log(va, J)
    if (!J) return `Не все данные введены`;
    resultTt = va / (3.6 * J);
    TT[x] = resultTt;
    return resultTt.toFixed(4);
  }

  function createSTD() {
    for (let x in STD) {
      formSTD.append(createDiv(x, STD, breakWayStdPrint));
    }
  }
  createSTD();

  // 2 формула - значение Sтд:
  function breakWayStd(va, Sj, L, C, x) {
    resultStd = Sj + va * t3 / 7.2 - L - C;
    STDRES[x] = resultStd;
    return resultStd.toFixed(2);
  }

  function breakWayStdPrint() {
    let line = '';
    for (let x in VA) {
      line += `<div><span>Sтд при ${x}(${VA[x]})</span><span>${breakWayStd(VA[x], STD.Sj, STD.L, STD.C, x)}</span></div>`;
    }
    resultSTD.innerHTML = line;
    breakWayTt1()

  }
  breakWayStdPrint()

  // 3 формула - значение Tt1:
  function breakWayTt1() {
    let line = '';
    for (let x in VA) {
      line += `<div><span>TT1 при ${x}(${VA[x]})</span><span>${VA[x] - (Math.sqrt(VA[x] ** 2 - (2 * STDRES[x]) / J + (t3 ** 2) / 4))}</span></div>`
    }
    resultTT1.innerHTML = line;
  }
```

```html
<h1>При торможении</h1>
<form>
    <div>
        <label>J1:</label>
        <input type="text" name="team" id="JGlobal" list="team_list">
        <datalist id="team_list">
            <option value="6.9">6.9 м3 мокрый</option>
            <option value="7.5">7.5 м3 сухой</option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>t1:</label>
            <select id="T1Global">
                <option disabled>выберите значение (надо выбрать - не будет просто так работать)</option>
                <option>1.0</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>t2:</label>
            <select id="T2Global">
                <option disabled>выберите значение (надо выбрать - не будет просто так работать)</option>
                <option>0.2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>t3:</label>
            <select id="T3Global">
                <option disabled>выберите значение (надо выбрать - не будет просто так работать)</option>
                <option>0.25</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form id="VaGlobal">
    </form>
    <button onclick="createVA()">+</button>
    <h1>Значение Tt</h1>

    <form id="formInputTt"></form>

    <h2 id="resultTt"></h2>
    <div id="resultTtTable">

    </div>
    <h1>Значение Sтд</h1>
    <form id="formInputStd">

    </form>

    <h2 id="resultStd"></h2>


    <h1>Значение Tt1</h1>
    <form id="formInputTt1"></form>

    <h2 id="resultTt1"></h2>
```

Comment: спасибо ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ ВАМ) Это было самое глобальное такое.. Я по аналогии уже доразвиваю Ваш код и доделаю остальные несколько формул) Вы очень хороший человек)

Comment: Одно уточнение - если последняя формула So автономная по сути от формул выше, то её делать в по аналогии с первой формулой, та что Tt? Там просто первый раз используется Va)

Comment: @Maks возможно. Любая реализация зависит от потребнойстей и желаемого поведения. Как только формула перестает быть зависимой от предыдущих расчетом, можно сразу считать.

Comment: я тут последнюю формулу Tt1 только не понял - там при скорости 38.5 (я на таких исходных данных проверял) оно должно выйти 0.9949. И формула там вроде выглядит так: resultTt1 = resultTt - (Math.sqrt(resultTt ** 2 - (2 * resultStd) / J + (t3 * t3) / 4)); а в Вашем варианте: ${VA[x] - (Math.sqrt(VA[x] ** 2 - (2 * STDRES[x]) / J + (t3 ** 2) / 4))}</span></div>`
    }
    resultTT1.innerHTML = line;
  }

Comment: решил, там надо подставить ТТ вместо VA сразу: line += `<div><span>TT1 при ${x}(${VA[x]})</span><span>${TT[x] - (Math.sqrt(TT[x] ** 2 - (2 * STDRES[x]) / J + (t3 ** 2) / 4))}</span></div>`

Comment: @Maks Решение выше, это пример того, как такое можно организовать, а не готовое решение под ваш проект. Так как даже по коду есть ряд моментов, которые не плохо было бы оптимизировать и изменить...

Comment: я утром уже глобалки свои позакидывал туда (чуть передклал под себя), кроме Va - её оставил Вашу, потом учто если её делать глобальную то эта тут не будет работать. Но это очень классная реализация) Я думаю людям, которые что-то похожее будут искать этот Ваше решение будет полезно) А мне осталось остальные формулы написать и реализовать как-то форму с Тп (следующую) чтобы сам вводил и считало, сейчас буду пробовать)

Comment: @Maks Вы лучше задавайте маленькие вопросы, на которые можно дать точный ответ. На такие большие и глобальные вопросы(Как переделать весь проект) мало кто отвечает. Лучше задавать предметные вопросы, допустим, есть такой кусок кода, хочу переделать, что бы работало так то, вот мои попытки, не получается сделать то-то. Ошибки прикладывайте. Тогда скорость и качество ответов будет лучше. Почитайте [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: спасибо за совет) Ну как я уже писал - когда доделаю эту страницу то это, по сути, будет самая глобальная такая проблема, которая уже решенная .. Дальше, думаю, в принципе по мелочам что-то будет или среднее)

Comment: ещё вопрос (утром хотел спросить ещё): на примере любого результата (даже первого Тт) - как сделать просто дубль этого результата (просто ещё 1 вывод - с ним действий не будет требоваться) - он будет просто в таблицу выводится потом после всех расчётов.

Comment: @Maks Можно задублировать строку, можно задублировать вывод нужных переменных, можно попробовать несколько раз вызвать нужную функцию. Не очень понятно, что значит просто задублировать. Лучше оформите отдельным вопросом, с минимальным кодом, дополнив его ожидаемым поведением

Comment: хорошо, я когда дойду до этого - создам вопрос)

Comment: Добрый день, сделал по аналогии еще 2 формулы ниже, вторая результат выводит (после Sa), a сама Sa в результате пишет NaN, не пойму в чём ошибка. Закинул на общедоступный везде сервис проверенный: https://codepen.io/Behemoth0/pen/VwGwzzq

Comment: @Maks Начнем с того, что по ссылке ничего не работает и ошибка не воспроизводится. Создайте отдельный вопрос, куда приложите проблемный код, а в codepen создайте полный, рабочий, пример. Догадка первая - вы пытаетесь выполнить математическую оперцию со строкой или null/undefined - надо дебажить

Comment: сделаем рабочий) Я пробовал дебажить, было несколько значений в line строке Sa undefined, но не смог решить проблему

Comment: закинул: https://codepen.io/Behemoth0/pen/PodoQjW?editors=1010

Comment: Там как раз с первой по последнюю формулу, и я ещё не понял как там результаты фиксить путём  return resultStd.toFixed(2); например. Пробовал пофиксить так ТТ1 и So - то формы ввода пропадали то ничего не работало